# Принять и послать Button id для query

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, bootstrap, table

Привет всем.

У меня есть некая таблица и кнопка Edit. Вывожу все на экран и каждая кнопка знает свой ID. Мне нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку Edit, его ID автоматически попало в написанной мной query.

Вот мой код с PHP

```js
$(".btn[data-target='#myModal']").click(function() {
  var columnHeadings = $("thead th").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  columnHeadings.pop();
  var columnValues = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  var modalBody = $('<div id="modalContent"></div>');
  var modalForm = $('<form role="form" name="modalForm" action="putYourPHPActionHere.php" method="post"></form>');
  $.each(columnHeadings, function(i, columnHeader) {
    var formGroup = $('<div class="form-group"></div>');
    formGroup.append('<label for="' + columnHeader + '">' + columnHeader + '</label>');
    formGroup.append('<input class="form-control" name="' + columnHeader + i + '" id="' + columnHeader + i + '" value="' + columnValues[i] + '" />');
    modalForm.append(formGroup);
  });
  modalBody.append(modalForm);
  $('.modal-body').html(modalBody);
});
$('.modal-footer .btn-primary').click(function() {
  $('form[name="modalForm"]').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="simple-little-table table" cellspacing='0'>

  <tr>
    <th>
      <p>&#8470;</p>
    </th>
    <th>
      <p>AD, Soyad, Ata adi</p>
    </th>
    <th>Shexsi nomre</th>
    <th>Shirket nomre</th>
    <th>WhatsApp nomre</th>
    <th>Tabel nomre</th>
    <!--<th>Ishe Qabul</th>-->
    <th>VOEN</th>
    <th>Sexsiyet</th>
    <th>Prava</th>
    <th>
      <p>Mehkumluq Haqqinda Arayis
      </p>
    </th>
    <th>4 shekil</th>
    <th>Telimat</th>
    <th>
      <p>Xidmet Muqavile
      </p>
    </th>
    <th>Bal</th>
    <th>nomre</th>
  </tr>

  <?php  
  $result =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `MY_TABLE` WHERE 1 and status=1");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
  {
     
     $id=$row["0"];
     $bal=$row["9"];
     $voen=$row["10"];
     $sexsiyet=$row["11"];
     $prava=$row["12"];
     $mahk=$row["13"];
     $photo=$row["14"];
     $telimat=$row["15"];
     $xidmet=$row["16"];
     
      echo '<tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><p>'.$row[1].' '.$row[2].' '.$row[3].'</p></td>
      <td><p>'.$row[4].'</p></td>
      <td><p>'.$row[5].'</p></td>
      <td><p>'.$row[6].'</p></td>
      <td><p>'.$row[7].'</p></td>';
      ?>
  <td>
    <p>
      <?php if($voen==1) {  echo '<input type="checkbox" checked />'; } else { echo '<input type="checkbox" />'; }?></p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <?php if($sexsiyet==1) { echo '<input type="checkbox" checked />'; } else { echo '<input type="checkbox" />'; }?></p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <?php if($prava==1) {  echo '<input type="checkbox" checked />'; } else { echo '<input type="checkbox" />'; }?></p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <?php if($mahk==1) {  echo '<input type="checkbox" checked />'; } else { echo '<input type="checkbox" />'; }?></p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <?php if($photo==1) {  echo '<input type="checkbox" checked />'; } else { echo '<input type="checkbox" />'; }?></p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <?php if($telimat==1) {  echo '<input type="checkbox" checked />'; } else { echo '<input type="checkbox" />'; }?></p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <p>
      <?php if($xidmet==1) {  echo '<input type="checkbox" checked />'; } else { echo '<input type="checkbox" />'; }?></p>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row[9]; ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo '<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" onclick=\'getValue('.$id.');\' data-target="#myModal" contenteditable="false" value=".$id.">'.$id.'</button>';?></td>
  <?php   ?>
  </tr>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="">?   </span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>

          <?php

    $s = mysql_query("Select * from MY_TABLE where id = $id");
    while($k = mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
     
    ?>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
              <?php echo $k."fdfd"; ?>
            </h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">AD</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" required>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
  }}
    ?>

</table>
```

Пример фотками

Фотка таблицы с кнопкой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно не послать VALUE в модал, а сделать id доступным для использования в query, что бы в зависимости от ID , мог вывести на экран данные.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну добавьте кнопке атрибут, и при клике из ивента возьмите `event.target.getAttribute('data-myCustomId')`. PS. Добавлять тег надо с меткой `data-<ваш текст>`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев `event.target.dataset('myCustomId')` ? ;-)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев я слаб в JS, по этому попросил помощь. Как в моем случае будет правильно написать это и где именно? P.S мне надо использовать это в query.

Comment: @OrkhanBagirov дак в вашем примере, при клике на кнопку у `event.target.getAttribute('value')` будет ваш идентификатор, используйте как хотите)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Оба варианта рабочие ;) Очень редко пользуюсь кастомными `data-` полями. Не знал про `dataset` опцию у `HTMLElement`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Спасибо за ответ и помощь, хочу задать глуппый вопрос) куда прописать это что бы смог прировнял к php переменной и дал select в query?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а где это спользовать парвильней? куда прописать это что бы смог прировнял к php переменной и дал select в query?

Comment: @OrkhanBagirov там где вы подписываетесь на клик по кнопке, туда и пишите. В функцию которая у вас есть придет первым аргументом  объект события `event`. У него есть свойство `target`, которая и будет вашей кнопкой. У неё вам нужно взять значение `value`.